# Opensea JS SDK createSellOrder method doesn't seem to work or silent failure

Tags: javascript, blockchain, nft

I am trying to create multiple sell orders for my NFTs on the rinkeby testnet. I am using the  script provided by OpenSea from this [repo](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-creatures) called sell.js

The issue is after I run the script, the method createSellOrder seems to run because I get the following output on my terminal but nothing else appears or happens. [image]

The first two lines are my own logging and the third line is what I guess is from createSellOrder.

My question is, what is the expected outcome/output of createSellOrder and how can I know it succeeded? For me it just prints the last line: creating proxy for acc... and stops.

When I check opensea, it doesn't have my nfts listed for sale so it obviously didn't work...

Comment: share the code snippet.

Comment: I've linked the code I'm using

Answer (score 0):

This type of issue tends to be fixed by removing all your node_modules and reinstalling using `yarn` instead of npm

Comment: What node version are you using? Did you try it out?